# Dynamic table cell height

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

Using the storyboard, I've created a custom cell for my table view, I've also created a custom class for it with all my properties.

Now, what would be the best way in making the cells height dynamic, where is the best way to do this?
Should I do this in the custom class for the cell? Or in my table view controller?

I imagine it would make more sense to do this in the custom class, but then how should I do this?
Once a specific label is filled in, it should change the height of the cell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot change the height of the cell from your custom drawing class.

You can do this in the viewController that has the UITableView only.
Either by specifying a hardcoded row height for all cells, or by using the

[`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)

and specifying a height for the cells here.
If you want to have different heights for the cells, you should check the indexpath.row property and return the desired height value.

In case you want to change the height of an already drawn in screen cell, you will have to reload that cell to reflect the change using this:

[`- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:)

Comment: Thanks, I seem to be able to set the height manually, but when is this function called? I have a few labels and the height should change accordingly, when I output the text of one of those labels, it just looks empty

Comment: If you change the height for cells that are visible you need to reload the rows to actually force the UITableView to call in the delegate cellForRowAtIndexPath for each visible cell, which means basically it will redraw the visible cells. So you should adjust your label height accordingly. If you are using custom drawn code, remember you will have to call the setNeedsDisplay method to force a drawRect reload of your custom draw class.

Comment: I managed to get it to work with the reloadRowsAtIndexPath, thanks!

Comment: To get back to this, at first start the cells are all the same height, I can call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths, but this will only change the size after you scroll thru the list.

Is there a way to get the height right without having to scroll first?

Comment: You don't have to scroll to reload the cells. Show us some code to help you. Something you are doing is not correct

Comment: Hi @Lefteris, I am trying this out, but I don't know where to start. I've already the three methods: numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath. I've also a method that calls a refresh when my data is updated. In the cellForRowAtIndexPath I've some custom code for my table cell layout. How can I change the cell height with heightForRowAtIndexPath? Is it triggered automatic when refreshing the data? Do I have to add something? And how do I get the different heights with indexpath.row?

Comment: If you implement the delegate `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` then you don't need to do anything. It will be called to get the cell Height for the cells whenever the datasource is refreshed.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code

```
-(CGFloat)heightForText:(NSString *)str width:(int)width font:(UIFont *)font lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode) lineBreakMode
{
    CGSize textSize;
    textSize = [str boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : font} context:nil].size;
    return textSize.height;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == self.yourTable)
    {
            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [self.yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
            return [self heightForText:[dict valueForKey:@"reviewDescription"] width:300 font:[UIFont fontWithName:kAppRegularFont size:15.0] lineBreakMode:0]+75;
    }
    return 70;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your view controller to be the delegate for the table view and then implement the following UITableViewDelegate method in the view controller:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: From what I can see is that this uses the height given in my storyboard, I use [cell.descriptionLabel sizeToFit], but it doesn't seem to use this new height

Answer (score 0):

Add these line into your "viewDidLoad" method

```
 self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = your height here

 self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

**Don't set default hight into delegate**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

}
```

Comment: you should use code syntax to format your post ! (canoot edit, queue is full) :/